# The name "Handles" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a script I am using

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Handles.Label(propellers[0].position, engine_rpm.ToString());
}
```

But when I try to build the project I get an error

> "the name Handles is not exist in the current context".

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The error can't be what you said it is based on the code you provided.

Comment: @AnouarHossni in general please add the exact error message just like you get it from the console (copy & paste) instead of a retyped version which doesn't reflect the actual names etc

Answer (score 2):

[`Handles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) is in the namespace `UnityEditor` which is completely stripped of during the build process. Wrap your method with the [preprocessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) `#if UNITY_Editor` and `#endif` (see [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)) and use the full qualified name `UnityEditor.Handles`

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        UnityEditor.Handles.Label(propellers[0].position, engine_rpm.ToString());
    }
#endif
```

Or otherwise make sure to also wrap the `using` statement

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Handles.Label(propellers[0].position, engine_rpm.ToString());
    }
#endif
```